# Google Workspace Marketplace SDK webhook notification

Tags: notifications, sdk, google-apps-marketplace, marketplace

I created application in Google Workspace Marketplace SDK, it is published, pricing are ready etc. However I can't find any information how I can create webhook notification for Marketplace action.

Scenario: Client bought license for our product in Google Marketplace. Google should somehow notify my service that USER bought access and that will give me propoer info to create account etc...

Problem is I don't see any section in Marketplace SDK related to this functionality. Documentation is lacking that information also or I can't find any related one.

Does anyone knows how I can set this? This should be I guess some basic functionality.

Comment: There's currently no transactions in the Google Workspace Marketplace, so there's no way for a user to buy a license. Your application can request the user to also sign into your service, for which they will need a license that you can sell, but that happens outside of the Marketplace.